# How to clone files or edit files in git as I have the URL ssh repo? HELP, GOOGLE did not help :(

Tags: git, github, ssh, repository

Never used git before. I need help to try and clone files to my laptop and edit the code available on the repo. I have been given the ssh url code to clone or access on git but the GUI is not help, and tutorials i have read are not much help at all.

Thank you, appreciated.

Comment: Are you against using the command line?

Comment: @GregHilston no. why do you ask? I never used git before... so i automatically went to git GUI instead of git BASH

Comment: I was going to write you out a list of commands to use with the command line, but saw you mentioned you were using a GUI. Just wanted some clarification before spending any time. Glad Quijote Shin helped you!

Comment: @GregHilston Thank you regardless, appreciate the thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to install `git` and have it in your local system  path

Don't know your system, so I can't recommend you a install procedure and if you need a GUI like tortoise (windows)

Then open a console

and type

```
 git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

This will copy the entire master inside your current directory

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!.... i dont understand why google hasnt got much on this stuff. I tried everywhere for such a simple answer. THANK YOU AGAIN! x.

BTW when i enter password... i am getting Permission denied, Please try again....? i am guessing my password is just wrong... or i dont have permission :S